# PowerShell - NoNewLine Write-Host parameter in SPLATTING

Tags: powershell, write-host, parameter-splatting

*(If there is something wrong with my english, i apologize in advance)* Hi, I don't know much about splatting, I have used it only 2 or 3 times, but this time I have to use it with `Write-Host`. I would like to add the `NoNewLine` parameter to the splatting, like this:

```
$splatting = @{ForegroundColor="Magenta"; BackgroundColor="Black"; NoNewLine}
```

But the console don't let me execute it, so I tried to set it as `$true`, but I get the error: `Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter'`. How can i do?

Comment: `-NoNewLine` is a switch, so try: `NoNewLine=$true`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala that's the correct answer, you should post it :)

Comment: Perhaps you mistakenly _quoted_ the `$true` value( `"$true"` or `'$true'`), which would explain your symptom. @AbrahamZinala's comment shows the proper solution.

Comment: You could also use [switch]::Present

Comment: @mklement0 `[switch]$NoNewLine = "$true"` totally explains the error message. Nice catch.